# How do I correct a circular import with Flask and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, circular-dependency

I'm working on a flask application that uses SQLAlchemy, and I have the models for the database declared in a different file '**db_schema.py**' from the main application file '**app.py**'. I am getting a circular import error when trying to import the models from **db_schema.py** back in to **app.py**.

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'User' from partially initialized module 'db_schema' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/deric/projects/python/flask/chatroom/chatroom/project/db_schema.py)
```

**db_schema.py**

```
from app import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime import datetime

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(25), unique = True, index = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(125), unique = False, index = False, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(30), unique = True, index = True, nullable = False)
    chatroom_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chatroom.id'))
    messages_sent = db.relationship('Message', backref='sender', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete')


class Chatroom(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    

class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    chatroom_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chatroom.id'))
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    content = db.Column(db.String(150), unique = False, index = True)
    time_sent = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique = False, index = True, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import Registration_Form


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sqlite3.db'
login_manager = LoginManager()
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from db_schema import User, Message, Chatroom

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter(id=user_id).first()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077599/flask-circular-dependency)

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to move the conflicted depedency variable `app` out to a third file. Import `app` from both `db_schema.py` and `app.py`.

Here's the [dependency graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph):

```
config.py (app) <---- db_schema.py (User, ...)
      ^                      ^
      |                      |
      +------- app.py -------+
```

In code:

`config.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sqlite3.db'
```

`db_schema.py`:

```py
from config import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# model classes: User, ...
```

`app.py`:

```py
from config import app
from db_schema import Chatroom, Message, User

login_manager = LoginManager()

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter(id=user_id).first()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If `db` seems misplaced in the `db_schema.py` file, you could move it out to `config.py` or its own file. You can rename `config.py` if you don't feel it represents what it does well.

Another way to resolve the dependency without more files is to provide a class or function that can be invoked to initialize a variable. This allows all files to be loaded before fulfilling the topological ordering requirements through function calls.

The canonical thread appears to be [Flask circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077599/flask-circular-dependency) which has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43077769/6243352) showing the function-based approach.

Also: if you use plain SQLAlchemy instead of Flask-SQLAlchemy, then there's no `SQLAlchemy(app)` call. This has other benefits of loose coupling such as better model portability, with the drawback that initial configuration of session scoping is a bit more tedious and error-prone.